# Undo file change during rebase

Tags: git

What i'm looking for is how to checkout a file during a git rebase merge conflict.  The situation I ran into today was during a git rebase I had to manually merge the file, and I messed it up.  During normal git usage I would just issue a `git checkout myfile`, and I tried that but the file was still in the state I left it.  What I wanted in this case was the file in its original failed merge state with the conflict markers so I could give it another go.  I ended up aborting the rebase and trying it again but I'd like something less drastic.  What am I missing?

Comment: You want the `-m` option to `git checkout`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
git checkout -m file
```

> To reproduce the automerged result (with conflict markers) of a
>   conflicted path file, using the three versions (base, ours and theirs)
>   recorded in the index. With versions of git up to v1.6.6 (released
>   recently), however, this is only possible until we "git add file" to
>   mark the path as resolved, at which point the three versions are
>   discarded from the index and replaced with the result of the merge.

Ref: http://gitster.livejournal.com/43665.html